# multi condition statement javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am doing a calculator for savings and I have the following multi-condition in Javascript, when I put it in dreamweaver I get a syntax error, but really don't understand where is the error.

**Here is the code:**

```
if (p<20000 && nnn=1) {
    document.kombpred.r2.value = mmm * nnn * bbb * 0.1;
}
else if (p>=20000 && nnn = 1) {
    document.kombpred.r2.value = 2000;
}
else if (p>=20000 && nnn > 1) {
    document.kombpred.r2.value = mmm * Math.pow(nnn,2) * bbb * 0.1;
}
else if (p<20000) {
    document.kombpred.r2.value = mmm * nnn * bbb * 0.1;
}
```

This is just the `if` statement, I have even other `if` statements but not with multiple conditions and the code is correct, but as soon as I insert this, something bad happens.

The words: `mmm`; `nnn`; `bbb`; are all `parseFloat()` numbers, like: `var mmm = parseFloat(m)`.

I also have declared all of them.

Comment: The thing which jumps out is `nnn=1` - assignment when you must mean comparison. Not sure this is strictly a syntax error though.

Comment: @Ben Parsons: Assignment is a valid expression, but here `p<20000 && nnn` is being assigned a value which *is* invalid.

Comment: The only thing I notice on mobile right now, is that you're setting 'nnn'  in the if condition,  you should use '=='  instead of '='  when comparing against a value. 
But that shouldn't give you an syntax error though - - -  Maybe it is an syntax error if strict mode is on, I don't know

Comment: @pimvdb quite right. I was reading it as `if (p<20000 && (nnn=1)) { }`, which does work as expected. Still, it's almost certainly a mistake either way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does the error say? My console says: invalid left-hand side assignment. You're doing comparisons like this `nnn=1` (which is the syntax for an assignment) when they should be `nnn == 1`.

Comment: Wooooow great :D...i needed to put nnn == 1 and it solved the problem. So in javascript i put only one equal sign when i assign s.m.th, and when i compare i should use two equal signs :). Thank you a lot!!!!

Comment: The second paragraph is not true. If it was evaluated as such it would be syntactically correct. Due to precedence, it is evaluated as `(p>=20000 && nnn) = 1` which is invalid (an assignment to an expression makes no sense - you can only assign to variables/properties).

Comment: @pimvdb You're correct, thanks for pointing that out. Removed.

Comment: May i ask even one thing? Can i change the onclick attribute of a button by changing option in the select tag. Like option1 gives the button one onclick action and option 2 gives another. Do i need a function for this?

Comment: @Genci. Yes that's possible. You need to listen to the `onchange` event of the select, and act accordingly. Read a little bit about binding events in Javascript: [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event), [2](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html). If you get stuck, make sure to ask a separate question rather than continuing this one.